# Can the following integrals be solved analytically?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, stochastic-processes, indefinite-integrals, stochastic-integrals

### Question

- Can the following integrals be solved analytically?

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\sigma^2 }{b^2} \int^T_t \left( e^{ -b(T- s)}  - 1 \right)^2  ds 
\end{eqnarray}

- where $\sigma, b > 0$, and $T \ge t \ge 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\sigma^2 }{b^2} \int^T_t \left( e^{ -b(T- s)}  - 1 \right)^2  ds
=
 \frac{\sigma^2 }{b^2}\Big( e^{ -2bT}\int^T_t  e^{ 2bs} ds  - 2e^{ -bT} \int^T_te^{ bs} ds +  \int^T_t   ds
\Big)
\end{eqnarray}
where $$\int^T_t  e^{ 2bs} ds = \frac{1}{2b}(e^{2bT}-e^{2bt})$$
$$\int^T_t  e^{ bs} ds = \frac{1}{2b}(e^{bT}-e^{bt})$$
$$ \int^T_t   ds = T-t$$

Answer (score 2):

The substitution $u:=T-s$ converts the problem to $$\frac{\sigma^2}{b^2}\int_0^{T-t}(e^{-2bu}-2e^{-bu}+1)ds=\frac{\sigma^2}{b^2}\left[\frac{-3+4e^{-b(T-t)}-e^{-2b(T-t)}}{2b}+T-t\right].$$